# how to solve getit shared preferences error?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, service-locator

I'm trying bloctesting for my project and getting the following error:

```
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart': Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null': Object/factory with  type SharedPreferences is not registered inside GetIt. 
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
```

Below are my sharedpreferences injection files

***shared_preference_injection_configuration.dart***

```dart
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

final GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

@injectableInit
Future<void> configureInjection(String env) async {
  await $initGetIt(getIt, environment: env);
}


Future<void> initDependencies() async {
  await _initSharedPref();
}

Future<void> _initSharedPref() async {
  final SharedPreferences sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  getIt.registerSingleton<SharedPreferences>(sharedPref);
}
```

***shared_preference_injection.dart***

```dart
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

@module
abstract class InjectionModule {
//injecting third party libraries
  @preResolve
  Future<SharedPreferences> get prefs => SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

Below lies the main method.It already has the configureinjection and initdependencies method but still gives me the same error.

***main.dart***

```dart
void main() async {
  // Make sure all bindings are loaded for easy localization
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  await configureInjection(Environment.prod);
  await initDependencies();

  // ignore: always_specify_types
  EasyLocalization.logger.enableBuildModes = [];

  // Load bloc Observer for debugging
  BlocOverrides.runZoned(() => SimpleBlocObserver());

  // Define main breakpoints for responsive_builder
  ResponsiveSizingConfig.instance.setCustomBreakpoints(
    const ScreenBreakpoints(desktop: PDesktopSize, tablet: PTabletSize, watch: PWatchSize),
  );

  // Set default locale to german style
  // Intl.defaultLocale = 'de_DE';

  // Load bloc Observer for debugging
  runZonedGuarded(
    () async {
      await BlocOverrides.runZoned(
        // Main Entry Point for our application
        // Translations wrapping around the whole app and start the structure for Cecht
        () async => runApp(
          EasyLocalization(
            supportedLocales: const <Locale>[
              Locale('en'),
              Locale('de'),
            ],
            path: 'assets/translations_v5',
            fallbackLocale: const Locale('de'),
            child: MyApp(),
          ),
        ),
        blocObserver: SimpleBlocObserver(),
      );
    },
    (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) => Logger().logWarning('${error.toString()} $stackTrace'),
  );
}
```

Comment: I am not sure. where is di.init() ?

Comment: @Mahi I have added some code but the error is same. Can you please check again?

Comment: did you called initDependencies() in main method?

Comment: @Mahi yes I have

Comment: please show  the main method.

Comment: Go to your main method and add

`configureInjection()`

Comment: @Denzel it already has it. I have added my main method. please check it.

Comment: @Mahi added it please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so when you're doing blocTesting then you need to register your packages again in the setup function in it which is in the case you are using getit for dependency injection.